# Пропадает форма PHP

Tags: php, html

После нажатия Зарегистрироваться пропадает форма, что не так?

```
<?php
$title = 'Регистрация';
include '/core/header.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST['ok'])){
    $login = trim($_POST['login']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    if($core['activate'] == 'off'){
        $check_login = assoc("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");
        $check_email = assoc("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    }else{
        $check_login = assoc("SELECT * FROM activate WHERE login = '$login'");
        $check_email = assoc("SELECT * FROM activate WHERE email = '$email'");
    }
    if(empty($login)){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('1 из полей осталось пустым!','error');exit;}
    if(empty($password)){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('1 из полей осталось пустым!','error');exit;}
    if(empty($email)){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('1 из полей осталось пустым!','error');exit;}
    if($check_login['login'] == $login){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('Такой логин уже зарегистрирован!','error');exit;}
    if($check_email['email'] == $email){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('Такая почта уже зарегистрирована!','error');exit;}
    if(!preg_match('|^[a-z0-9\-]+$|i', $login)){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('Кириллица запрещена в логине!','error');exit;}
    if(!preg_match('|^[a-z0-9\-]+$|i', $password)){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('Кириллица запрещена в пароле!','error');exit;}
    if(mb_strlen($login) > 32 or mb_strlen($login) < 3){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('Логин должен состоять от 3 до 32 символов!','error');exit;}
    if(mb_strlen($password) > 32 or mb_strlen($password) < 3){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('Пароль должен состоять от 3 до 32 символов!','error');exit;}
    if(mb_strlen($email) > 32 or mb_strlen($email) < 3){header('Location: /register.php');$_SESSION['messages'] = msg('Почта должна состоять от 3 до 32 символов!','error');exit;}
    $password = md5($password);
    $hash = md5(rand(100000,999999));
    if($core['activate'] == 'off'){
        query("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email) VALUES ('$login', '$password', '$email')");
        setcookie('id', $login, time() + 86400 * 365);
        setcookie('password', $password, time() + 86400 * 365);
        header('Location: /');
        $_SESSION['messages'] = msg('Вы успешно зарегистрировались!','success');
    }else{
        query("INSERT INTO activate (login, password, email, hash) VALUES ('$login', '$password', '$email', '$hash')");
        mail($email, 'Активация аккаунта', 'Ссылка на активацию аккунта: http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/activation.php?login='.$login.'&password='.$password.'&email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash);
        header('Location: /');
        $_SESSION['messages'] = msg('Вам на почту прийдет письмо с ссылкой на активацию аккаунта!','success');
    }
    exit;
}
echo '<div class="block" style="max-width:800px;margin:0 auto;">
Регистрация<hr>
<form action="" method="POST">
<table><tr>
<td width="20%">
Логин</td><td><input name="login" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td width="20%">
Пароль</td><td><input name="password" type="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td width="20%">
E-Mail</td><td><input name="email" type="email"></td>
</tr></table>
<button name="ok">Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
</div>';
include '/core/footer.php';
```

Comment: Падает - понятие растяжимое. Подскажите, какую ошибку выдаёт система?

Comment: ошибок нету, вывод ошибок включен. проблема в том что после нажатия кнопки зарегистрироваться пропадает всё после шапки, после перезагрузки тоже нечего, пока не перейти снова на линк /register.php

Comment: Если у Вас падает форма, значит ошибки точно есть. Их необходимо вывести, иначе мы никак не сможем Вам помочь. В Вашем случае ошибки могут быть либо в самом скрипте php, либо в запросе в БД. Для вывода ошибок в php используйте `error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On` Для Вывода ошибок mysql используйте `mysql_error` или `mysqli_error` в зависимости от того, чем пользуетесь.

Comment: И в строке `assoc("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");` замените `assoc` на `query`.

Comment: error_reporting = E_ALL ...это в php файл верно? сейчас заменю

Comment: Да, всё верно. И вывод ошибок `mysql` там же. Это Вам нужно просто для отладки, потом всё уберёте.

Comment: Сейчас сделаю всё

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\mogames.com\core\header.php:22) in W:\domains\mogames.com\register.php on line 17

Comment: Вот Вам и ошибка. Нельзя использовать `headers` в случае, если уже документ был объявлен.

Comment: а что мне делать тогда?

Comment: У меня вышке только header.php подключен там все мета теги и дизайн

Comment: Если Вы объявили начало документа, то он уже начинает формироваться и не даст Вам использовать другие `headers`. Проще говоря - нельзя ничего выводить на страницу.  Как один из вариантов - можно в `php.ini` указать параметр `output_buffering = 14096`  Или избавиться от `echo` заменив на `include`.

Comment: php.ini не помог, так инклудиться только header.php и всё, шапка

Comment: Тогда избавляйтесь от добавления записей в сформированный документ. Или на крайний случай, попробуйте `header` для перехода на другую страницу заменить на `echo "<script>window.location.href='/register.php</script>";
`

Comment: мне немного это помогает exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /index.php'>"), но это долго писать

Comment: Долго писать? Хм. Ваш код весь настолько долго писать, что это-то как раз не особо большой код. Вам могло бы сильно помочь если бы вы перешли на другой уровень и начали бы отделять логику от представления (MV*-паттерны), но для этого нужен качественный скачок и революция в сознании, готовы ли вы к этому? Пока вы обходитесь мелкими улучшениями и кардинально тут мало что поменяет ситуацию.

Comment: я еще позавчера на ядрах игр с пабликов работал, там по коду еще дольше и уровень еще ниже моего

Answer (score -2):

```
exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /index.php'>");
```

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы вы писали объяснение к своему ответу.